# Show this converges in distribution to 0

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence

> Let $\{ X_n:n \geq 1 \}$ such that 
>   $$f_{X_n} = \begin{cases} (n-1)/2 &\mbox{if } -1/n <x<1/n \\ 
> 1/n & \mbox{if } n<x<n+1 \end{cases}$$
>     Show that this converges to $0$ in distribution.

I am struggling to find the distribution function for this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For every positive $x$, $P(X_n\leqslant-x)=0$ for every $n$ large enough, and $P(X_n\geqslant x)\to0$ when $n\to\infty$.